# Update collection object using Underscore / Lo-dash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have two collections of objects. I iterate trough collection A and I want when ObjectId from A matches ObjectId from B, to update that Object in collection B.

Here is what I got so far:

```
   var exerciseIds = _(queryItems).pluck('ExerciseId').uniq().valueOf();
        var item = { Exercise: null, ExerciseCategories: [] };
        var exerciseAndCategories = [];

        //this part works fine
        _.forEach(exerciseIds, function(id) {
            var temp = _.findWhere(queryItems, { 'ExerciseId': id });
            item.Exercise = temp.Exercise;
            exerciseAndCategories.push(item);
        });

        //this is problem
        _.forEach(queryItems, function (i) {
            _(exerciseAndCategories).where({ 'ExerciseId': i.ExerciseId }).tap(function (x) {
                x.ExerciseCategories.push(i.ExerciseCategory);
            }).valueOf();
        });
```

**EDIT**

Link to a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7vpg/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var exerciseIds = _(queryItems).pluck('ExerciseId').uniq().valueOf();
var item = {
    Exercise: null,
    ExerciseCategories: []
};
var exerciseAndCategories = [];

//this part works fine
_.forEach(exerciseIds, function (id) {
    var temp = _.findWhere(queryItems, {
        'ExerciseId': id
    });
    var newItem = _.clone(item);
    newItem.Exercise = temp.ExerciseId;
    exerciseAndCategories.push(newItem);
});

//this is problem
_.forEach(queryItems, function (i) {
    _(exerciseAndCategories).where({
        'Exercise': i.ExerciseId
    }).tap(function (x) {
        return _.forEach(x, function(item) {
            item.ExerciseCategories.push(i.ExerciseCategory);
        });
    }).valueOf();
});

// exerciseAndCategories = [{"Exercise":1,"ExerciseCategories":["biking","cardio"]},{"Exercise":2,"ExerciseCategories":["biking","cardio"]}]
```

Main problem was that `tap` returns the array, not each item, so you have to use `_.forEach` within that.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B7vpg/3/)**

Comment: Didn't help, when I write this line of code:  logger.log(exerciseAndCategories);, I can see that ExerciseCategories: are still empty, so collection exerciseAndCategories was not updated

Comment: Updated with a fiddle. Needed to `return` from `tap`

Comment: Thanks for fiddle but I didn't get result I expected, maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I've edited your fiddle bit and added comment about how I want result to look like

Comment: @hyperN What do you want the final array to look like? Like this: `[{"Exercise":1,"ExerciseCategories:["bike","cardio"]},{"Exercise":2,"ExerciseCategories:["bike","cardio"]}`? If that's it, the update I'll have in a few will give you just that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35376/discussion-between-hypern-and-kalley)